# DotNetCore ILogger error parameter logger value cannot be null

Tags: c#, .net-core, serilog

I have included Serilog in my project. It works well with other controllers.

When I try to pass the logger reference to a different class(instantiated) I am facing the below error

**Message = "Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'logger')"**

Below is pseudo code

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Xml;
using Serilog;
using Serilog.AspNetCore;
using Serilog.Core;
using Serilog.Sinks;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace SomeNameSpace
{
    public class EmployeeDAO : IDisposable
    {
        //DataUpload Service implements IDataUpload
        private readonly IDataUpload dataUpload;
        
         private readonly ILogger<EmployeeDAO> log;
        public readonly ILogger<DataUploadService> dataLogger;
    
        public EmployeeDAO(ILogger<EmployeeDAO> logger)
        {
            log = logger;
        }
    
        private void SaveData(object obj)
        {
            switch (obj.GetType().Name)
            {
                case "SaveData":
                    this.dataupload = new DataUploadService(a, b, obj, dataLogger);
    //Error thrown at above line logger is null
                    break;
                default:
                    log.LogError($"Logging Some Error");
            }
        }
        }
}
```

I this to be done in a different way ?
Please provide a better way to handle this.

Comment: You should be injecting DataUploadService instead of manually creating an instance of it

Comment: You never set `this.logger` to a value (at least not in the code fragment shown). You have a parameter to the ctor called `logger`, but that is a different reference and type and has nothing to do with the class member `logger` - appart from the name, which is actually confusing here.

Comment: I have updated the code. DataUploadService implements IDataUpload. Hope its clear now, can you provide some pseudo code on how to resolve this error

Comment: There's still nothing that sets the `datalogger` field, which is what you're using. This code will also not compile, since `datalogger` is not `dataLogger`. Why not simply inject `ILogger<DataUploadService>` in exactly the same way as you're injecting `ILogger<EmployeeDAO>`? A cleaner approach would be to abstract `DataUploadService` itself behind an interface and inject an `IDataUploadServiceProvider` (although if all this class does is instantiate and invoke a `DataUploadService`, that's probably overkill -- as is the class itself, for that matter).

Comment: I corrected the variable name dataLogger to be dataLogger. If I inject ILogger<DataUploadService> the same way as ILogger<EmployeeDAO> then I have to modify the class EmployeeDAO at multiple places where it is referenced.   Is there a simple way to resolve this, The DataUploadService does implement a Interface

Answer (score 0):

You do need to instantiate the field `public readonly ILogger<DataUploadService> datalogger;` that you pass in as a parameter to the `DataUploadService`.

Since you inject the other private field for `logger` you could do the same for `dataLogger`.

Constructor injection:

```
        private readonly ILogger<EmployeeDAO> log;
        public readonly ILogger<DataUploadService> dataLogger;
    
        public EmployeeDAO(ILogger<EmployeeDAO> logger, ILogger<DataUploadService> dataLogger)
        {
            log = logger;
            dataLogger = dataLogger;
        }
```

You will ofcourse need to register the dependency the same way as your `ILogger<EmployeeDAO> logger` is registrated.

Comment: Do you suggest a better way to do this @DannyBoy ? Could you provide any example

Comment: I added an example in my answer above.

Answer (score 0):

Your primary error is that `dataLogger` is never set.
To Resolve that issue you can do like Danny Boy suggest, and inject the logger as well.

However, I would suggest that you inject `DataUploadService` as well, instead of constructing it in your class. Optionally you can inject `Func<DataUploadService>` to lazy inject the service. [If you want to lazy inject it, you need a third party container like Autofac](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/dependency-injection-guidelines#default-service-container-replacement).